After creating a team, why TeamsAsyncOperation stays with status "notStarted" forever?
I create a new Team using POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams.
I expect TeamsAsyncOperation to complete with status "succeeded" but instead it stays with status "notStarted" but the Team is really created.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('sqdfsdfs')/operations/$entity",
  "id": "qsdfsqdfqsdf",
  "operationType": "createTeam",
  "createdDateTime": "2024-06-10T15:07:57.08827Z",
  "status": "notStarted",
  "lastActionDateTime": "2024-06-10T15:07:57.08827Z",
  "attemptsCount": 1,
  "targetResourceId": "70ef1c22-7ac1-4da6-a979-ac49b97559f4",
  "targetResourceLocation": "/teams('qsdfsqdfsqdf')",
  "Value": "{\"apps\":[],\"channels\":[],\"WorkflowId\":\"westeurope.4b9c94e9-aa41-4891-b4b7-09aa5d89d91b\"}",
  "error": null
}

What is the correct way to assume that the Teams is created if I can't rely on the operation status?

We tried creating a Team using Graph explorer and we did not receive anything in response body but the status code "Accepted 202", with which we confirmed that the API call is successful and team has been created. Could you please let us know how did you get the "status": "notStarted". We see teamsAsyncOperation doc only for Chats.

Yes you have to follow the link in the header "Location" of the response to get this status. Here is an extract of the documentation : "If successful, this API returns a 202 Accepted response that contains a link to the teamsAsyncOperation.". I need to know when the team is ready for subsequent calls.

I have exactly the same problem. I wait 5 and more minutes and the operation never starts (shown in the /Location).

And it seems to be a bug with the graph API, because the team is actually visible in https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/teams/manage/ and users can actually post messages to the team. Yet the graph API still says "status":"notStarted"

An incident has been raised to check this issue. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Thank you, can you link me to the issue?

The bug is internal to Microsoft and cannot be shared outside.
